# WW1 shell case markings

Tags: world-war-one, identification, weapons, shell-casings

The inscription listed below is on a shell case which was in my grandmothers house. Can any one tell me what they mean.

> BRC
>
> QF. 18.PR
>
> V11
>
> FS
>
> TR
>
> MH
>
> 9.11.15

[image: Picture of a highly polished shell case; letters are barely visible at the bottom]

Answer (score 16):

It's a shell for the standard British [Ordnance QF 18-pounder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_QF_18-pounder) field gun.

---

Shell markings will normally include the following:

- Calibre and numeral.
- Manufacturers “ initial ” or “ Trade Mark.”
- Date of completion of manufacture,
- C.S. or F.S. denoting whether the casing is made from Cast or Forged Steel

---

In this case, we have

- QF 18 PF meaning it's a Quick Fire 18-pounder
- VII means it's a mark VII shell
- FS means the shell casing is made from forged steel.
- 9.11.15 is the manufacture date

I'd guess that BRC is the manufacturer of the shell casing, and (TR over MH) is the monogram of the filling station.

---

A lot of filling stations were established during the first world war. There is a list of initials used by filling stations in 1918 in [Explanatory List of Service Markings to be found on ammunition and ammunition packages in use with the Field Armies. 1918](http://bulletpicker.com/pdf/Explanatory%20List%20of%20Service%20Markings.pdf). Sadly, it doesn't include the markings on your shell casing. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an earlier edition online.

The [1915 treatise on Ammunition](http://bulletpicker.com/pdf/Treatise%20on%20Ammunition,%201915.pdf) from the War Office also has more detail about the 18-pounder ammunition.

---

Comment: Thank you. That’s very helpful. My grandmother worked in the Hereford Munitions factory during WW1.